# Probability of drawing at least 4 candy baars of the same type

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

Say I have 3 types of candy bars in my bag, Milky Way, Snickers, and Kit Kat. There are 7 of each candy bar. If I draw candy bars out of the bag without replacement, how many candy bars must I draw to guarantee that I have:

a) at least 4 candy bars of the same type
b) at least 4 Milky ways.

I'm really bad at counting so I'm not sure how to do this. For a) I think it's 10 because if I keep drawing a different bar each time, it would take 10 times to get at least 4 of the same bar. For b) using the same logic, I think it would be 12 times since 4*3. Or am I supposed to use combinations.

Comment: For a), consider the "worst" case possible. What can happen if you draw 21 candy bars? b) uses a similar idea.

Comment: This has nothing to do with probability, does it?

Comment: Hey, if you feel like your question was sufficiently answered, please hit the check mark on the one of the answers to close this thread.

Answer (score 1):

First, rename the candy bars so that you don't have a spelling burden:

- 3 types of candy bars: A, B, C;
- 7 each

> how many candy bars must I draw to guarantee that I have at least 4 candy bars of the same type?

Well, you will have to draw 4 candy bars at least to guarantee that you have "at least 4 candy bars". Now, do you need more?

If they are all the same then you are done. But in the "worst" case like

A, B, C, C

you need 3 more A (or B), or 2 more C.

Let us continue and still consider the "worst" case.

A, A, B, C, C

A, A, B, B, C, C

...

A, A, A, B, B, B, C, C, C

Aha, 10 is the number you are looking for!

Now, let's *prove* it. Suppose you take randomly 10 candy bars and you still don't have "4 candy bars" of any particular type. But then you would have at most 9 candy bars in total. Contradiction.

On the other hand, the experiment above tells you that any number less than 10 would not work.

Now your turn to do Problem (b).

Answer (score 1):

The word **guaranteed** implies that there is no possibility to get something different than the desired outcome. This means that you can't use stochastic to solve this problem. In a simple case like yours you can instead just use the "worst case" approach:

a) In order to certainly get 4 candy bars of the same type the worst possible scenario would be to draw 3 candy bars of type A, 3 candy bars of type B and finally 3 candy bars of type C. This means you could possibly draw a total of 9 candy bars without getting 4 of the same kind. Number **10** will guarantee you 4 identical bars.

b) In order to certainly get a single candy bar of a specific type (in your case Milky Way) you would have to deplete all other candy bars first. That would be 7 Snickers, 7 Kit Kats and only then you can be sure to pull out 4 Milky Ways. This adds up to a possible total of **18** draws.